# Error running WSGI application, no module named django

Tags: django, deployment, web-deployment, wsgi

I have some problem while deploying my website to Pythonanywhere.com

i've done all things step by step like it was in a guide-line
and at the end i catch an error:

error log

```
2022-03-27 20:07:23,699: Error running WSGI application 2022-03-27
20:07:23,700: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' 2022-03-27 
20:07:23,700:   File "/var/www/usitingshit_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py",
line 88, in <module> 2022-03-27 20:07:23,700:     from django.core.wsgi
import get_wsgi_application 2022-03-27 20:07:23,700:
```

i've tried to change wsgi.py file

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/usitingshit/deploy_course_work/'
if path not in sys.path:
  sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] ='/home/usitingshit/deploy_course_work/vodprojectstroy_site/wsgi.py'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

structure of my project:
[image]
[image]

has anybody had the same problem? how can i fix that? sorry if this question is silly, coz i am a beginner in django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is preinstalled on PythonAnywhere, so it's basically available out of the box.  However, if you want to use a virtual environment for the web app, you need to ensure that Django is available in it too.  The error you're seeing is most probably indicating that you set a virtual environment for the web app, but did not install Django in it.

Comment: can i install it using bash and command pip install django ?

Comment: Of course -- make sure the relevant virtual env is activated when you run the pip command.